# Runtime.exec() in Hadoop on Azure environment

Tags: azure, hadoop

This question is related to Hadoop on Azure environment.

I am trying to use Runtime.exec() to execute a batch script in the reduce function. I could not get this running in Hadoop on Azure environment while it runs fine in the Hadoop on Linux. I tested the Runtime.exec() code snippet in my desktop (windows 7) environment and it runs fine there. I have made sure that I consume the output and error streams of the sub-process after Runtime.exec().

The batch script contains the below ( a single command):

c:\hdfs\mapred\local\taskTracker\nabeel\jobcache\job_201207121317_0024\attempt_201207121317_0024_r_000001_0\work\tool.exe
-f c:\hdfs\mapred\local\taskTracker\nabeel\jobcache\job_201207121317_0024\work\11_task_201207121317_0024_r_000001.out 
-i c:\hdfs\mapred\local\taskTracker\nabeel\jobcache\job_201207121317_0024\attempt_201207121317_0024_r_000001_0\work\input.txt

I distribute the tool.exe and input.txt files using Distributed cache and it creates a symlink from the working directory. tool.exe and input.txt points to the actual files in the jobcache directory.

2012-07-16 04:31:51,613 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner: Creating symlink: /hdfs/mapred/local/taskTracker/distcache/-978619214658189372_-1497645545_209290723/10.73.50.78tool.exe <- \hdfs\mapred\local\taskTracker\nabeel\jobcache\job_201207121317_0024\attempt_201207121317_0024_r_000001_0\work\tool.exe
2012-07-16 04:31:51,644 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner: Creating symlink: /hdfs/mapred/local/taskTracker/distcache/-4944695173898834237_1545037473_2085004342/10.73.50.78input.txt <- \hdfs\mapred\local\taskTracker\nabeel\jobcache\job_201207121317_0024\attempt_201207121317_0024_r_000001_0\work\input.txt

The reducer gives the below error when it runs.

Command Execution Error: Cannot run program 
"cmd /q /c c:\hdfs\mapred\local\taskTracker\nabeel\jobcache\job_201207121317_0024\work\11_task_201207121317_0024_r_0000011513543720767963399.bat": 
CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

In another case, I tried running the same but without using the absolute paths.. The output stream from the sub-process is shown below:

c:\hdfs\mapred\local\taskTracker\nabeel\jobcache\job_201207121317_0022\attempt_201207121317_0022_r_000000_0\work>tool.exe -f /hdfs/mapred/local/taskTracker/nabeel/jobcache/job_201207121317_0022/work/1_task_201207121317_0022_r_000000.out
-i input.txt

I do not know how the job working directory paths and distributed cache works in Hadoop on Azure environment. Could you please let me know if I am missing something here (or) there is something I need to take care of while using Runtime.exec() in Hadoop on Azure environment.

Thanks,

**.*,*._**
Reply to sender | Reply to group | Reply via web post | Start a New Topic

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Hadoop. But the error message seems to be obvious. It would be better if you can check whether the file exists.

c:\hdfs\mapred\local\taskTracker\nabeel\jobcache\job_201207121317_0024\work\11_task_201207121317_0024_r_0000011513543720767963399.bat

Best Regards,

Ming Xu

Comment: Yeah.. I have access only to the head node in HoA platform, not to the nodes that actually runs the mapper / reducer.. But in any case, I could open this file through my program and read the contents.. This confirmed the existence of the .bat file..